# Discussing Java development on Mountain Lion

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need to discuss compatibility for Java development on OSX 10.8 Is SO the appropriate place for this or is it better suited for Ask Different?

Sample question:

With lion the first time java attempts to run it prompts you to download the JRE/JDK which I believe is still apple java and not the open JDK. Will this same behavior sill be there with Mountain Lion. (note we still need 1.6.x)

Comment: I'd lean towards SO, but you might want to give us a sample question.

Answer (score 11):

Do not ask in Ask Different. Almost anything programming related is explicitly excluded in the [FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). Also remember that Stack Overflow is not for discussions, it is for specific questions. If you are looking to discuss, I would suggest going into [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) and asking there.

Comment: Although downloading the JRE I would expect to be on topic on AskDifferent as any user would need to know that not just developers

Comment: I actually did ask on AskDifferent specifically regarding the JRE/JDK and received an answer from someone using Mountain Lion and Java.